# Mockito mocks with Spring: "Argument passed to verify() is not a mock!"

Tags: spring, javabeans, mockito

I used the code from [this blog](http://narkisr.com/blog/2008/2647754885089732945) to inject Mockito mocks in my unit tests. However, before the mock is autowired it gets wrapped by Spring in a JDK proxy. This causes any verify(autowiredMock) to throw **"Argument passed to verify() is not a mock!"**. The exception is thrown when Mockito is checking that the argument passed to verify(..) is a valid Mockito mock object in this method:

```
private static Method getCallbacksSetter(Class type, String methodName) throws NoSuchMethodException {
    return type.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, new Class[]{ Callback[].class });
}
```

My question is how to tell Spring not to proxy Mockito mock beans which I register in the BeanFactoryPostProcessor? Please note that I would like to avoid setting proxy-target-class="true".

Thanks

Comment: Well `proxy-target-class` is the only way to do it - why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: Because CJLIB requires that interface implementation classes had accessible no-arg constructors and most of my classes have private no-arg or autowired multi-arg constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you autowire the mock into a setter method, you can unwrap it manually there.

```
@Autowired public setMockedService(MyServiceInterface service) {
    mockedService = unwrapped(service) // to implement unwrapped(), you might use AOPUtils
}
```

It's ugly, but it is a way out without `proxy-target-class`

On a side note, if mocking is giving you this much pain, shouldn't you be looking at a stub solution?

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of Mockito (currently 1.9.0) has fixed this issue changing the algorithm that detects whether an object is a mock or is not.